# $owner role is not working

Tags: node.js, loopback

I am trying to give access only to owner of book in but it is not working.I have relationship between user and books.I have seen every question about loopback acl but I don't know where I am making mistake. This is my boot file

```
  var User = app.models.userData;  
User.create([
  {username: 'John', email: 'john@doe.com', password: 'opensesame',bookId:""},
  {username: 'Jane', email: 'jane@doe.com', password: 'opensesame',bookId:""},
  {username: 'Bob', email: 'bob@projects.com', password: 'opensesame',bookId:""}
], function(err, users) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('Created users:', users);

  // create project 1 and make john the owner
  console.log("This is users[0] " ,users[0].books);
  users[0].books.create({
    name: 'project1',
    price: 100
  }, function(err, project) {
    if (err) throw err;
    User.update({id:users[0].id},{bookId:project.id},function(err,docs){
        if(err) throw err;
        else{
            console.log("Updated",docs);
        }
    });
    console.log('Created project:', project);
  })
  users[1].books.create({
    name: 'project2',
    price: 100
  }, function(err, project) {
    if (err) throw err;
    User.update({id:users[1].id},{bookId:project.id},function(err,docs){
        if(err) throw err;
        else{
            console.log("Updated",docs);
        }
    });
    });
});
```

And This is my usersData.json

```
"relations": {
"books": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "book",
  "foreignKey": "ownerId"
}
"acls": [
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
},
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property":"findById"
}
```

This is my books.json

```
 "relations": {
"userData": {
  "type": "belongsTo",
  "model": "userData",
  "foreignKey": "bookId"
}


 },

  "acls": [
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
},
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property":"findById"
}
```

],

I know there are many questions related to this I have seen every question about this but it is not working.Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: are you also using remoteMethod to use those models ? if it is, you can add accessType to it

Comment: Could you please update your question to provide the following information: a) Full contents of *usersData.json*; b) Full contents of *books.json*; c) the request URL which is not working; d) response or error data for this request. As for now there are several potential points of failure so your update will narrow the problem.